# Сохранение предпочтений пользователя в выборе цветовой схемы при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, localstorage

У меня на сайте есть 2 темы(светлая/темная), они меняются по нажатию кнопки (через смену стилей. Для светлой light-theme.css, для темной - dark-theme.css). Хочу сделать, чтоб стиль css не менялся при обновлении страницы, т.е. если пользователь уже нажал кнопку и тема изменилась на темную, то при перезагрузке странице или переходе на другую вкладку оставалась также темная тема. Как это можно корректнее сделать? Если можно, хотелось бы полный код, так как ввиду моим скудных познаний в программировании, боюсь, что из примера я мало что пойму.

**Вот код JS, который отвечает за смену стилей:**

```
// Выбираем кнопку
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
// Выбираем таблицу стилей
const theme = document.querySelector("#theme-link");
// Отслеживаем щелчок по кнопке
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Если текущий адрес содержит "light-theme.css"
  if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "css/light-theme.css") {
    // …то переключаемся на "dark-theme.css"
    theme.href = "css/dark-theme.css";
    // В противном случае… 
  } else {
    // …переключаемся на "light-theme.css"
    theme.href = "css/light-theme.css";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно сохранять выбранные стили пользователя

Модифицируем текущий код добавляем сохранение значения в localStarage

```
  // Выбираем кнопку
  const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
  // Выбираем таблицу стилей
  const theme = document.querySelector("#theme-link");
  // Отслеживаем щелчок по кнопке
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Если текущий адрес содержит "light-theme.css"
    if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "css/light-theme.css") {
      // …то переключаемся на "dark-theme.css"
      theme.href = "css/dark-theme.css";
      // Сохраняем значение в хранилище
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'css/dark-theme.css');
      // В противном случае…
    } else {
      // …переключаемся на "light-theme.css"
      theme.href = "css/light-theme.css";
      // Сохраняем значение в хранилище
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'css/light-theme.css');
    }
  });
```

Добавляем в код функцию, которая будет загружаться при загрузке страницы

```
  function setTheme() {
    theme.href = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'css/light-theme.css'
  }
```

в HTML, в тег body добавляем

```
<body onload="setTheme()">
```

Готово!

Comment: А не знаете почему `onload` для `body` может не выполняться? Были сайты, где оно почему-то не выполнялось.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Проверьте, возможно что то переустанавливало обработчик onload. Я с таким особо не сталкивался

Comment: Я такое встречал на сайте майкрософт при авторизации, перекидывает на белый экран и все. А в onload должно выполнять отправку формы.

Comment: @OliverPatterson ну вот за сайт майкрософт не отчечу ) Может там что то ломалось и все белело..

Comment: Огромнейшое спасибо за ответ, все работает отлично