# Как сохранить input.value?

Tags: javascript, html

Я сделал переключение темы сайта:

```
function changeTheme(isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        document.body.setAttribute('dark', '');
        addToCart()
    } else {
        document.body.removeAttribute('dark');
        getCartData()
    }
}
```

я хочу чтоб при перезагрузке страници сохранналась галочка в input.

Comment: Сохраните значение в localStorage, а при загрузке страницы считывайте это значение и выставляйте. Вот тут почти ваш вопрос и ответ про [сохранение темы сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1503031/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для этого `localStorage`

```
function changeTheme(isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        document.body.setAttribute('dark', '');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
        addToCart()
    } else {
        document.body.removeAttribute('dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
        getCartData()
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить значение из `localStorage` используйте `localStorage.getItem('theme');`

Подробнее здесь:
https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage

Comment: `Используйте для этого localStorage` -- почему именно `localStorage`, что в нём такого?