# Как синхронизировать тему на двух страницах?

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

Например, есть два файла index.html и index2.html. Нужно, чтобы при переходе с одной страницы на другую тема не менялась.

Вот код для смены темы:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".dark-version");

const theme = document.querySelector("#theme-link");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "style.css") {
    theme.href = "light.css";
  } else {
    theme.href = "style.css";
  }
});


function toggledark() {
    if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "style.css") {
    theme.href = "light.css";
  } else {
    theme.href = "style.css";
  }
```

Comment: Сохраняйте значение в localStarage, а при загрузке страницы подставляйте значение. [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1503031/1503042#1503042)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вставить тему на url и потом при загрузке берешь тему с url и theme.href = ''; и менаешь на что нужно.
toggledark внутри этой функции тоже меняшь тему на url